# Confusing xCode error

Tags: xcode, uitextview, warnings

I'm getting a really confusing error, I've import a class with his header from other project, both files are exactly the same but in my new project is not working. Even when I try to replace isKindOfClass: by myself the method does not find any UIwhatever object. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you imported "#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>"?

Comment: As simple as that, I knew I was missing something! Thank you very much gagarwal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```